# unable to get a specific list of elements using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i have never used this library before so i apologize if this may sound like a stupid question

so, what is going on is that i want to extract some specific text from this website

`https://www.unieuro.it/online/`

i already have browser.js, and all the requirements to make puppeteer work

so i just navigate to that website and make it search for something

<sub>keep in mind this is just a code sample</sub>

```
await page.goto("https://www.unieuro.it");
await page.waitForSelector('input[name=algolia-search]');
await page.type("input[name=algolia-search]","echo dot")
await page.click(".icon-search")
```

nothing wierd so far it works as intended, however after this step things get wierd really quickly.

first of all i was complitely unable to make it wait for any selector.
i tried to make it wait for the class `collapsed hits__hit`, for the element article, or even the section, it would time out every single time, so i just gave up and used

```
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
```

from here i'm trying to extract the elements that have the class: `product-tile`

specifically, i need the title, which is inside a `a` element as `textContent`

that `a` element is inside a `div` with the class `product-tile__title` so what i tried is a simple eval

```
var name = await page.$$eval(".product-tile__title" el => {
    el.map(el => el.querySelector("a").textContent))
    return el
})
```

this did not work at all, it gives me a bunch of empty objects inside an array

so i tried to install an extension called puppeteer recorder, and i tried to use the code it generated which is

```
 const element1 = await page.$('.collapsed:nth-child(1) > .product-tile > .item-container > .info > .title')
```

in this case `element1` does contain something, but it is in no way related to the title

and right now i'm stuck, im complitely unable to get the object i need in anyway and the results on the internet are not helping.

<sub>as a side note:</sub>

<sub>i wish there was a simpler way to make a scraper in node, why must all the libraries be so complicated and never work like you want them to</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has super long load times for me, probably because I'm on the other side of the planet from Italy, and some strange behavior. When I ran the search by typing with Puppeteer, the page returns 17000 results that seem totally unfiltered. I didn't bother to figure out why because I was able to go directly to the search results page using https://www.unieuro.it/online/?q=echo%20dot:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setDefaultTimeout(10 ** 5);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    req.resourceType() === "image" ? req.abort() : req.continue();
  });
  await page.goto("https://www.unieuro.it/online/?q=echo%20dot");
  await page.waitForSelector(".product-tile__title");
  const titles = await page.$$eval(
    ".product-tile__title ",
    els => els.map(e => e.textContent)
  );
  console.log(titles.map(e => e.trim()));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Output:

```js
[
  'Amazon Echo Dot',
  'Amazon Echo Dot (4th gen)',
  'Amazon Echo Dot (4th Gen)',
  'Amazon Echo Dot (4th gen)',
  'Amazon Echo Dot (4th gen)',
  'Amazon Echo Dot (4th gen)'
]
```

I haven't tested this extensively (for example, on pages with tons of results), and there should be plenty of opportunity to improve load times by profiling and blocking irrelevant requests.

A probably better approach is to just [hit the API directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878732/6243352) and skip Puppeteer entirely:

```js
const url = "https://mnbcenyfii-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser; JS Helper (2.28.0)&x-algolia-application-id=MNBCENYFII&x-algolia-api-key=977ed8d06b718d4929ca789c78c4107a";
const body = `{"requests":[{"indexName":"sgmproducts_prod","params":"query=echo%20dot&hitsPerPage=20&maxValuesPerFacet=20&page=0"}]}`;
fetch(url, {method: "post", body})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.status);
    }
    
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => data.results[0].hits.map(e => e.title_it))
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

You can port this to Node easily with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: wow thank you, i didn't even know they had an api, and no, its not you, the page is just terrible, that is why i kinda assumned they closed their apis, anyhow i already managed to find a solution on my own in the end, i will still mark this as solution because it's the same thing i did